# Diophantine equation $n^2+23=2^{2k}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all solutions (if any)  to $n^2+23=2^{2k}$. I've tried computing mod low integers but found nothing contradictory.

Comment: Hint: $2^{2k}$ is a square, hence $23$ is a difference of two squares. I'm sure you know what to do next.

Comment: This pretty much solves it, thanks (I was in the algebraic number theory state of mind)

Comment: 23=(2^k-n)(2^k+n), 2^k=n+1=23-n, n=12, K=ln(12)/ln(2) not integer. I guess what you need is that n and K are both integers. Then no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n^2+23=2^{2k}\implies(2^k+n)(2^k-n)=23\implies2^k+n=23\text{ and }2^k-n=1\implies2^{k+1}=24$$

(Ah, I didn't notice quasi's comment below the OP until after posting. Or Ivan's!)

Comment: This is what I did after reading Ivan's comment, so I guess I'll mark this answer

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is not divisible by $3$, the number $n^2+23$ is divisble by $3$, hence it cannot be a power of $2$

If $n$ is divisible by $3$, we have $n^2+23\equiv 2\mod 3$, hence $n^2+23$ cannot be a perfect square.

Hence, the equation has no integral solutions.

Comment: Why not just reduce the equation as is mod $3$?  I.e., $n^2+23=2^{2k}=4^k\implies n^2-1\equiv1$ mod $3\implies n^2\equiv2$ mod $3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, this is even more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^{2k}-\left(2^k-1\right)^2=2^{k+1}-1$, for $k\ge4$, the difference between consecutive squares is at least $31$. Thus, $2^{2k}-23$ cannot be a square for $k\ge4$.

For $k\le2$, $2^{2k}-23\lt0$, so it cannot be a square.

This leaves $k=3$ and $2^6-23=41$, which is not a square.

Thus, there are no solutions to $2^{2k}-23=n^2$.